# Error when multiplying input value in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input, drop-down-menu

I have 2 lists (conversion from kilometers to miles etc.). When I'm trying to use input value to calculate (so "X * 1.609" for kilometers to miles) I have an error NaN.

```js
const inputPlace = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputPlace").value);

const config = {
 "kilometers": {
    "miles": inputPlace * 1.609,
    "yards": "Convert km to yd",
    "feet": "Convert km to ft",
    "inches": "Convert km to in"
  },
  "meters": {
    "miles": "Convert m to mi",
    "yards": "Convert m to yd",
    "feet": "Convert m to ft",
    "inches": "Convert m to in"
  },
  "centimeters": {
    "miles": "Convert cm to mi",
    "yards": "Convert cm to yd",
    "feet": "Convert cm to ft",
    "inches": "Convert cm to in"
  },
  "milimeters": {
    "miles": "Convert mm to mi",
    "yards": "Convert mm to yd",
    "feet": "Convert mm to ft",
    "inches": "Convert mm to in"
  }
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
   const metricValue = document.getElementById("metric").value;
   const impValue = document.getElementById("imperial").value;
   
   document.getElementById("aaa1").innerHTML = config[metricValue][impValue].toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
              <input type="number" id="inputPlace">
                
                <select name="metric" id="metric">
                  <option value="kilometers">km</option>
                  <option value="meters">m</option>
                  <option value="centimeters">cm</option>
                  <option value="milimeters">mm</option>
                </select>

                <select name="imperial" id="imperial">
                  <option value="miles">mi</option>
                  <option value="yards">yd</option>
                  <option value="feet">ft</option>
                  <option value="inches">in</option>
                </select>

                <button id="btn">Click</button>
                <p id="aaa1">Placeholder</p>
```

(Please only look at first example - km to mi)
How to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, this one is simple. In the first line of your code, you are getting the value of the input, which is a blank string (the user hasn't entered anything yet! You're executing that line once the page loads), which when you try to convert to an `int` results in "Not a Number". Instead, you should get the value of the number *when* you press the `click` button, not once the page loads (you also have to create a function to dynamically calculate the value):

```js
function calc(value) {
  // creating a function to re-calculate the value
  const config = {
    "kilometers": {
      "miles": value * 1.609,
      "yards": "Convert km to yd",
      "feet": "Convert km to ft",
      "inches": "Convert km to in"
    },
    "meters": {
      "miles": "Convert m to mi",
      "yards": "Convert m to yd",
      "feet": "Convert m to ft",
      "inches": "Convert m to in"
    },
    "centimeters": {
      "miles": "Convert cm to mi",
      "yards": "Convert cm to yd",
      "feet": "Convert cm to ft",
      "inches": "Convert cm to in"
    },
    "milimeters": {
      "miles": "Convert mm to mi",
      "yards": "Convert mm to yd",
      "feet": "Convert mm to ft",
      "inches": "Convert mm to in"
    }
  }
  return config;
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const metricValue = document.getElementById("metric").value;
  const impValue = document.getElementById("imperial").value;
  const inputPlace = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputPlace").value.replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll(" ", ""));

  document.getElementById("aaa1").innerHTML = calc(inputPlace)[metricValue][impValue].toFixed(2); // calling a function that returns an object instead of just using the object
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputPlace">

<select name="metric" id="metric">
  <option value="kilometers">km</option>
  <option value="meters">m</option>
  <option value="centimeters">cm</option>
  <option value="milimeters">mm</option>
</select>

<select name="imperial" id="imperial">
  <option value="miles">mi</option>
  <option value="yards">yd</option>
  <option value="feet">ft</option>
  <option value="inches">in</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
<p id="aaa1">Placeholder</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing, do you know how to do it so it calculates with decimal places? It won't calculate 1.5 * 1,609 or 4.34 * 1,609 correctly

Comment: You can't add commas (`,`) inside. What you can do is replace all the spaces and commas before parsing it to an int. I updated the answer.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually you can't enter commas or spaces inside input values, so in the real world you should be fine. By the way, if I answered your question I'd appreciated if you selected it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: As below, I should have used parseFloat instead of parseInt. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Once all the conversion equations are entered this will recalculate **all** of them on every click as well as creating a new object, which removes most of the advantage of having a lookup table to begin with. The other answer, storing methods in a lookup table and accessing only the needed function at any given time, is a far more sensible solution.

Comment: @pilchard Good point; use the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood my [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70115330/219661) a little bit. There are 4 main problems with the code:

1. The values stored in `config` were supposed to be methods
2. You're calling `toFixed` on what is essentially a method without every actually executing the method to get a result
3. You're reading the value of the input before the user had a chance to enter anything.
4. If you want to support the user entering decimals use `parseFloat` not `parseInt`

```js
const config = {
  "kilometers": {
    "miles": v => v * 1.609,
    "yards": "Convert km to yd",
    "feet": "Convert km to ft",
    "inches": "Convert km to in"
  },
  "meters": {
    "miles": "Convert m to mi",
    "yards": "Convert m to yd",
    "feet": "Convert m to ft",
    "inches": "Convert m to in"
  },
  "centimeters": {
    "miles": "Convert cm to mi",
    "yards": "Convert cm to yd",
    "feet": "Convert cm to ft",
    "inches": "Convert cm to in"
  },
  "milimeters": {
    "miles": "Convert mm to mi",
    "yards": "Convert mm to yd",
    "feet": "Convert mm to ft",
    "inches": "Convert mm to in"
  }
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const metricValue = document.getElementById("metric").value;
  const impValue = document.getElementById("imperial").value;
  const inputPlace = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputPlace").value);
  
  const fn = config[metricValue][impValue];
  document.getElementById("aaa1").innerHTML = fn(inputPlace).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputPlace">

<select name="metric" id="metric">
  <option value="kilometers">km</option>
  <option value="meters">m</option>
  <option value="centimeters">cm</option>
  <option value="milimeters">mm</option>
</select>

<select name="imperial" id="imperial">
  <option value="miles">mi</option>
  <option value="yards">yd</option>
  <option value="feet">ft</option>
  <option value="inches">in</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
<p id="aaa1">Placeholder</p>
```

NOTE: The above will only work with kilometers-miles selected as thats the only one with a valid function as the value!

Comment: Thank you for your help once more! parseFloat works just fine. However I'll stick to the code above, it's earier for me to understand

Comment: @Gibon no problem. Just so you're aware the code in the other answer, when you put all you different conversaions in, will calculate every single one of them every time. Not very efficient. This answer will only calculate the one selected.

Comment: @Gibon Im also happy to explain anything you don't understand